# Synchronous Jake Node.js task

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, jake

Can someone help me with closing the database after two models are added to the database?  I've tried reading

http://howtonode.org/intro-to-jake

[Node.js and Jake - How to call system commands synchronously within a task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755819/node-js-and-jake-how-to-call-system-commands-synchronously-within-a-task)

and the github readme at
https://github.com/mde/jake

but still can't seem to figure it out.  Here's an excerpt from the readme

*Cleanup after all tasks run, jake 'complete' event
The base 'jake' object is an EventEmitter, and fires a 'complete' event after running all tasks.
This is sometimes useful when a task starts a process which keeps the Node event-loop running (e.g., a database connection). If you know you want to stop the running Node process after all tasks have finished, you can set a listener for the 'complete' event, like so:*

```
jake.addListener('complete', function () {
  process.exit();
});
```

As it is now, it's closing the connection before it even opens it.

```
// db connect
var db = require('./schema');

desc('Seed MongoDB with initial data');
task('seed', [], function () {

    //******* Populate the database
    var user1 = new db.userModel({ email: 'x@x.com', password: 'x', phone: x });
    user1.save(function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('user: '+user1.email +' saved');
        }
    });
    var user2 = new db.userModel({ email: 'x', password: 'x', phone: x });
    user2.save(function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('user: '+user2.email +' saved');
        }
    });

    db.mongoose.connection.close();
    console.log('Closed mongodb connection');
});
```

**Edit:**
I was able to accomplish what I was going for using parallel flow from the parseq module.

```
par(
  function() {
    fs.readFile("file1", this);
  },
function() {
  fs.readFile("file2", this);
},
function done(err, results) {
  ...
}
);
```

**Edit2:**
So I REALLY appreciate all the help.  I also saw you were the maintainer of parseq :). Thx for that!  I'm still struggling with this last bit and my function is hanging and not calling done() when function 5 is complete.  I'm sure I'm calling 'this' incorrectly.  Any advice?

```
seq(
    function f1() {
        var user = new db.userModel({ email: 'x'
                        , password: 'x'
                        , phone: x });
        user.save(this);
    }, 
    function f2(err, value) {
        var user = new db.userModel({ email: 'x'
                        , password: 'x'
                        , phone: x });
        user.save(this);
    }, 
    function f3(err, value) {
        var merchant = new db.merchantModel({ name: 'x'
                        , logourl: 'x' });
        merchant.save(this);
    }, 
    function f4(err, value) {
        var merchant = new db.merchantModel({ name: 'x'
                        , logourl: 'x' });
        merchant.save(this);
    }, 
    function f5(err, value) {
        db.merchantModel.findOne({ name: 'x' }, function(err, merchant) {
            var coupon = new db.couponModel({ merchant_id: merchant.id
                            , name: 'x'
                            , imageurl: 'x'
                            , expiration: Date.UTC(2013,3,15) });
                            //, expiration: new Date(2013,3,15) }); //alternate date creation method
            coupon.save(this);
        });
    }, 
    function done(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('successfully seeded db');
        }
        db.mongoose.connection.close();
        console.log('Closed mongodb connection');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call `db.mongoose.connection.close` after both save functions have completed.  Easiest would be to nest the save calls (but not the prettiest).

```
var user1 = new db.userModel({ email: 'x@x.com', password: 'x', phone: x });
user1.save(function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('user: '+user1.email +' saved');
    }
    var user2 = new db.userModel({ email: 'x', password: 'x', phone: x });
    user2.save(function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('user: '+user2.email +' saved');
        }
        db.mongoose.connection.close();
        console.log('Closed mongodb connection');
    });
});
```

You should then start looking into a flow control library to make your code simpler.

same thing using parseq:

```
var seq = require("parseq").seq;

seq(
  function f1() {
    var user1 = new db.userModel({ email: 'x@x.com', password: 'x', phone: x });
    user1.save(this);
  }, function f2(err, value) {
    var user2 = new db.userModel({ email: 'x', password: 'x', phone: x });
    user2.save(this);
  }, function done(err) {
    // check err here
    console.log('Closed mongodb connection');
  }
);
```

to ignore some errors selectively, here's how one function could look like:

```
function f1() {
    var self = this;
    var user1 = new db.userModel({ email: 'x@x.com', password: 'x', phone: x });
    user1.save(function(err) {
      if (err === SOMETHING_TO_IGNORE) {
        self(null);
      else {
        self(err);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you.  Any suggestions for flow control library?  Extra credit if you can modify my code to work with one.

Comment: So this works, however, the whole function stops executing if user1 fails validation.  It's fine I can just recreate the db everytime, but ideally I would like to be able to add a user3 to the code and have it be added by running the script when user1 & user2 are already created.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: yes, that's normal and expected with the code I provided.  You'd need something a bit more elaborate to ignore specific errors.  I'll update my answer with some pointers.

Comment: look how I created a copy of this in self variable in my last edit.  the this inside the function inside save() is not the same as the one in f5().  Then you use coupon.save(self);

Comment: Cannot upvote you enough for this.  Missed that part the first time through.