# Execute and get the output of a shell command in node.js

Tags: node.js, shell, command-line-interface

In a node.js, I'd like to find a way to obtain the output of a Unix terminal command. Is there any way to do this?

```
function getCommandOutput(commandString){
    // now how can I implement this function?
    // getCommandOutput("ls") should print the terminal output of the shell command "ls"
}
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate, or does it describe something completely different? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183307/node-js-execute-command-synchronously-and-get-result

Comment: [This](http://davidwalsh.name/sync-exec) might interest you.

Comment: Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-spawn

Comment: **See Also**: [Execute a command line binary with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20643470/1366033)

Comment: For anyone who wants to execute a command on button click, check the next.js way here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71646984/execute-server-side-shell-script-on-button-click

Answer (score 209, accepted):

This is the method I'm using in a project I am currently working on.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function execute(command, callback){
    exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr){ callback(stdout); });
};
```

Example of retrieving a git user:

```
module.exports.getGitUser = function(callback){
    execute("git config --global user.name", function(name){
        execute("git config --global user.email", function(email){
            callback({ name: name.replace("\n", ""), email: email.replace("\n", "") });
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Is it possible to make this function return the command's output? (That's what I was trying to do.)

Comment: thats what that code does. take a look at the example at the edit I have just made

Comment: @AndersonGreen You wouldn't want the function to return normally with the "return" keyboard, because it is running the shell command asynchronously. As a result, it's better to pass in a callback with code that should run when the shell command is complete.

Comment: Ouch, your first sample ignores the possibility of an error when it calls that callback. I wonder what happens to `stdout` if there is an error. Hopefully deterministic and documented.

Comment: what is the point of the `execute` wrapper?

Comment: You should mention how to `exec` commands with user supplied arguments safely.

Comment: @Boris you are free to edit the 9 years old answer

Answer (score 93):

If you're using node later than 7.6 and you don't like the callback style, you can also use node-util's `promisify` function with `async / await` to get shell commands which read cleanly.  Here's an example of the accepted answer, using this technique:

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const exec = promisify(require('child_process').exec)

module.exports.getGitUser = async function getGitUser () {
  // Exec output contains both stderr and stdout outputs
  const nameOutput = await exec('git config --global user.name')
  const emailOutput = await exec('git config --global user.email')

  return { 
    name: nameOutput.stdout.trim(), 
    email: emailOutput.stdout.trim()
  }
};
```

This also has the added benefit of returning a rejected promise on failed commands, which can be handled with `try / catch` inside the async code.

Comment: Have you tried this? I'm getting `{ stdout: string, stderr: string }` as a result for the `await exec(...)`

Comment: Yeah, I should have clarified that this gives you the _full_ shell output, including both stdout and stderr.  If you want just the output, you could change the last line to: `return { name: name.stdout.trim(), email: email.stdout.trim() }`.

Answer (score 42):

You're looking for [child_process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child;

child = exec(command,
   function (error, stdout, stderr) {
      console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
      console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
      if (error !== null) {
          console.log('exec error: ' + error);
      }
   });
```

---

As pointed out by Renato, there are some synchronous exec packages out there now too, see [sync-exec](http://davidwalsh.name/sync-exec) that might be more what yo're looking for. Keep in mind though, node.js is designed to be a single threaded high performance network server, so if that's what you're looking to use it for, stay away from sync-exec kinda stuff unless you're only using it during startup or something.

Comment: In this case, how can I obtain the output of the command? Is is "stdout" that contains the command-line output?

Comment: Also, is it possible to do something similar without using a callback?

Comment: Correct, stdout contains the output of the program. And no, it's not possible to do it without callbacks. Everything in node.js is oriented around being non-blocking, meaning every time you do IO you're going to be using callbacks.

Comment: Note that if you're looking for using javascript to do scripty kinda things where you really want to wait on output and that sort of thing, you might look at the v8 shell, d8

Comment: @hexist there are some `Sync` methods natively available, even so IMHO it should be avoided

Comment: @hexist Is the v8 shell compatible with existing node.js libraries?

Comment: I haven't tried, but I would guess no. See my edits about sync-exec, it sounds like it may let you do what you want in node.js.

Comment: Trying to capture stdout and and set it to var. Tried things like returning stdout or setting it to externally defined variable and that's not working. I've been searching the net for two days trying to find a simple way of running a command and capturing the output without using something like `exec-sync`, as I want to be able to run the command async.

Comment: i like this solution but I think there may be an error on the first line. It worked after I dropped the `.exec` part on ` require('child_process').exec;`

Answer (score 32):

### Requirements

This will require Node.js 7 or later with a support for Promises and Async/Await.

### Solution

Create a wrapper function that leverage promises to control the behavior of the `child_process.exec` command.

### Explanation

Using promises and an asynchronous function, you can mimic the behavior of a shell returning the output, without falling into a callback hell and with a pretty neat API. Using the `await` keyword, you can create a script that reads easily, while still be able to get the work of `child_process.exec` done.

### Code sample

```
const childProcess = require("child_process");

/**
 * @param {string} command A shell command to execute
 * @return {Promise<string>} A promise that resolve to the output of the shell command, or an error
 * @example const output = await execute("ls -alh");
 */
function execute(command) {
  /**
   * @param {Function} resolve A function that resolves the promise
   * @param {Function} reject A function that fails the promise
   * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
   */
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    /**
     * @param {Error} error An error triggered during the execution of the childProcess.exec command
     * @param {string|Buffer} standardOutput The result of the shell command execution
     * @param {string|Buffer} standardError The error resulting of the shell command execution
     * @see https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback
     */
    childProcess.exec(command, function(error, standardOutput, standardError) {
      if (error) {
        reject();

        return;
      }

      if (standardError) {
        reject(standardError);

        return;
      }

      resolve(standardOutput);
    });
  });
}
```

### Usage

```
async function main() {
  try {
    const passwdContent = await execute("cat /etc/passwd");

    console.log(passwdContent);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.toString());
  }

  try {
    const shadowContent = await execute("cat /etc/shadow");

    console.log(shadowContent);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.toString());
  }
}

main();
```

### Sample Output

```
root:x:0:0::/root:/bin/bash
[output trimmed, bottom line it succeeded]

Error: Command failed: cat /etc/shadow
cat: /etc/shadow: Permission denied
```

### Try it online.

[Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/SpiffyThirdInterfacestandard).

### External resources

[Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

[`child_process.exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback).

[Node.js support table](https://node.green/).

Comment: This is the cleanest option in my opinion and reminiscent of https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs (but simpler).

Answer (score 23):

Thanks to Renato answer, I have created a really basic example:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec

exec('git config --global user.name', (err, stdout, stderr) => console.log(stdout))
```

It will just print your global git username :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the util library that comes with nodejs to get a promise from the exec command and can use that output as you need. Use destructuring to store the stdout and stderr in variables.

```js
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

async function lsExample() {
  const {
    stdout,
    stderr
  } = await exec('ls');
  console.log('stdout:', stdout);
  console.error('stderr:', stderr);
}
lsExample();
```

Comment: Basically the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/50335035/6243352

Answer (score 4):

you can use `ShellJS` package.
ShellJS is a portable (Windows/Linux/OS X) implementation of Unix shell commands on top of the Node.js API.
see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs#execcommand--options--callback

```
import * as shell from "shelljs";

//usage:
//exec(command [, options] [, callback])

//example:
const version = shell.exec("node --version", {async: false}).stdout;
console.log("nodejs version", version);
```

Comment: I get "TypeError: shell.exec is not a function" when running this solution. I'm using Node v16.10.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Any ideas?

Comment: Look at the documentation, e.g. https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs#examples. There the first line looks like this: `import shell from 'shelljs';`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an async await TypeScript implementation of the accepted answer:

```js
const execute = async (command: string): Promise<any> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const exec = require("child_process").exec;
    exec(
      command,
      function (
        error: Error,
        stdout: string | Buffer,
        stderr: string | Buffer
      ) {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
          return;
        }
        if (stderr) {
          reject(stderr);
          return;
        } else {
          resolve(stdout);
        }
      }
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: Why not use `util.promisify`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest and fastest way to accomplish it is using the response given by Damjan Pavlica.

Expanding over his answer, if you would like to implement separate handler functions for different listeners, `Nodejs` in its version `LTS v20` provides the `spawn` method of `ChildProcess`.

```
const { spawn } = require('node:child_process');
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});
```

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/child_process.html#asynchronous-process-creation

In my particular case I was interested in achieving this in a Windows OS environment and using Powershell.

Most of the answers here worked with only one caveat, your command must start with `powershell.exe`

```
const { exec } = require('node:child_process');

exec('powershell.exe ls -Name', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  console.log(stdout);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If anyone is looking for a CLI way to run a node script without a file, use the `-e` argument and put your node code in quotes like this:

```bash
node -e "console.log(process.env.PATH.split(':'))"
```

This is an easy way to inspect your path. :)