# How To Execute Windows Shell Commands (Cmd.exe) with Node JS

Tags: node.js, cmd, windows-shell

I would like to

```
C:\>ACommandThatGetsData > save.txt
```

But instead of parsing and saving the data in the console, I would like to do the above command with **Node.JS**

How to execute a shell command with **Node.JS**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [node.js shell command execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458508/node-js-shell-command-execution)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the output of a shell command in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941083/get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-in-node-js)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could also try the [node-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cmd) package:

```
const nodeCmd = require('node-cmd');
nodeCmd.get('dir', (err, data, stderr) => console.log(data));
```

On newer versions of the package, the syntax changed a little:

```
const nodeCmd = require('node-cmd');
nodeCmd.run('dir', (err, data, stderr) => console.log(data));
```

It does not support `Promises` directly, but you can easily wrap them inside one:

```
const nodeCmd = require('node-cmd');
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    nodeCmd.run('dir', (err, data, stderr) => {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        } else {
            resolve(data, stderr);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This resolved the brick wall I was hitting! Thanks :)

Comment: get function is not defined in newer version. New exmaple can be found here https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cmd

Comment: The node-cmd module internally uses child_process only => (https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/node-cmd)

Comment: can i use this with ```await```and promises ? Thank you

Comment: Not sure if if supports Promised directly, but even if it doesn't, you can always wrap it inside a promise; if `err` is non-falsy, you would call `reject(err)`; otherwise, you'd call `resolve(data)`. Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise in order to see how to use `resolve` and `reject` to implement a Promise.

Answer (score 18):

<strike>Use [`process.execPath()`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_execpath):</strike>

```
process.execPath('/path/to/executable');
```

#### Update

I should have read the documentations better.

There is a [Child Process Module](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) which allows to execute a child process. You will need either `child_process.exec`, `child_process.execFile` or `child_process.spawn`. All of these are similar in use, but each has its own advantages. Which of them to use depends on your needs.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is old, but it helped me get to my solution using promises.
Also see: [this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941083/execute-and-get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-in-node-js/50335035#50335035)

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

async function runCommand(command) {
  const { stdout, stderr, error } = await exec(command);
  if(stderr){console.error('stderr:', stderr);}
  if(error){console.error('error:', error);}
  return stdout;
}


async function myFunction () {
    // your code here building the command you wish to execute ...
    const command = 'dir';
    const result = await runCommand(command);
    console.log("_result", result);
    // your code here processing the result ...
}

// just calling myFunction() here so it runs when the file is loaded
myFunction();
```