# Run powershell commands from my Angular 6 web application

Tags: javascript, html, angular, powershell, web-applications

I have just started angular and typescript and created a web application using the command "ng new myapp". And i want to run powershell commands from my web application. Can anyone help me with this?

This is my file structure that i have after creating the project-
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular4/images/final_file_structure.jpg

Comment: explain more.why do you want to do that

Comment: i am creating a dashboard for running powershell commands from my web application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute windows powershell command using childprocess and nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274084/how-to-execute-windows-powershell-command-using-childprocess-and-nodejs)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible by sole Angular application. If the website would be able to execute commands that would be a major security issue. If you want to execute some powershell commands by pressing buttons in Angular you would need a f.e. node server with [win32 api library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/win32-api). In angular you would be just calling node api and server would execute commands.

Comment: This is my file structure that i have after creating the project where should i add the code- tutorialspoint.com/angular4/images/final_file_structure.jpg

Comment: @thechosenone either in different directory as separate app or you could put it in `/api/`. Really it's up to you.