# Javascript terminal emulation in windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, terminal, tty

I am attempting to use Javascript / NodeJS to build a new command line / terminal for personal use but I am running into some issues. I can't not seem to find a decent way of interacting with the windows command line from my own Javascript.

I understand that by default browsers do not allow javascript to interact with system based commands so I was considering using socketIO or something of the sort.

I was planning on using Electron (chromium).

I'm wondering what would be a good direction to pull the windows command line env into my window.

In all honesty, even just taking the existing output from the CMD would be a good enough start.

Comment: Are you asking how to perform console IO from NodeJs running on windows? OR how to write a console application using NodeJs while parsing the arguments? Your question is a little confusing, which is probably why you were downvoted (or maybe it was becase you didn't provide any examples of things you have tried)

Comment: Have you read anything like this: https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/command-line/how-to-prompt-for-command-line-input

Comment: I am seeking to build out essentially a terminal emulator that owrks with windows. There are plenty of options in other languages. But I want to be able to interact with the windows command prompt / env from a client facing application written in JS.

Comment: Have you seen somethign like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919347/how-to-execute-windows-shell-commands-cmd-exe-with-node-js

Comment: Hyperjs, Xtermjs, ShellJs for ui stuff, then use node child process

Answer (score 2):

In a Windows console window you can execute a JavaScript script using the command "cscript". It has been a while since I have done that so I was reviewing my previous work.

I know nothing about NodeJS but as I was searching for help to refresh my memory, I found several articles and StackOverflow answers that seem relevant. I hope these help.

[Command Line JavaScript](http://javascript.cs.lmu.edu/notes/commandlinejs/)

[How do I prompt users for input from a command-line script? - docs.nodejitsu.com](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/command-line/how-to-prompt-for-command-line-input)

[How to Read from stdin in JavaScript](http://www.polyglotbits.com/how-to-read-from-stdin-in-javascript/)

[node.js - How to read from stdin line by line in Node - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086849/how-to-read-from-stdin-line-by-line-in-node)