# How do I communicate with a native executable from a nodejs server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am evaluating what to use for a simple web service.
I have a c++ program that takes some queries and generates html pages.

How do I call this executable from a server I am writing in javascript?

If there is a better tool for the task, suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I haven't done that but looking at the code of https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport seems like he calls c++  from node.js.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941083/get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-in-node-js

Comment: @curieux: note the distinction between using c++ code in a node module and using node with an existing c++ application...

Comment: also consider IPC solutions like redis and zeromq

Answer (score 2):

If you want to launch the C++ program as a separate process, take a look at [`ChildProcess`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) with special attention on [`spawn()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options), and [`exec()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback).

If you want to treat it as a dynamically linked shared object, look at [Addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html).