# How to obtain local ip address of PC using Javascript in MAC Safari Browser?

Tags: javascript, safari, mobile-safari, ip-address

How to obtain local ip address of PC using Javascript in MAC Safari Browser? Looking for solution which works with Safari Web Browser.

I mean **local ip address of device/PC network interface**. Not public ip address as of "what is my ip"

Comment: I would start looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript

Comment: @Alan I mentioned clearly. I am not looking for public ip address. I am looking for PC local ip address.

Comment: Ok, I would first learn the linux command to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322485/how-to-i-get-the-primary-ip-address-of-the-local-machine-on-linux-and-os-x and then pass it through javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941083/get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-in-node-js . Hopefully this will point you to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

1. Mostly - you can't.
2. But - here come WebRTC's RTCPeerConnection command and enables you to do that.
3. References:

   Accessing local IP with WebRTC: [Link](https://hacking.ventures/local-ip-discovery-with-html5-webrtc-security-and-privacy-risk/)

   Live working example: [Link](http://net.ipcalf.com/)

   Example of detecting all IP addresses in your local range: [Link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1878671/enumhosts.html)

Hope that helps
  MAC addresses in JavaScript: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385/mac-addresses-in-javascript)