# run terminal commands in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler

I'm trying to write a web crawler program using [quickscrape](https://github.com/ContentMine/quickscrape), after I type

```
quickscrape \
  --url https://peerj.com/articles/384 \
  --scraper journal-scrapers/scrapers/peerj.json \
  --output peerj-384
  --outformat bibjson
```

and hit the "Enter"
in my terminal, the library will generate the result from the crawler and put them into a folder.

Now I want to write a javascript progarm so that is will call these terminal commands for me, but I am not sure how to interact with terminal in node.js.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute and get the output of a shell command in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941083/execute-and-get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-in-node-js)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think child_process is that you need. https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

```
let exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('quickscrape --url https://peerj.com/articles/384 --scraper journal-scrapers/scrapers/peerj.json --output peerj-384 --outformat bibjson', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    //...
})
```