# How to make normal function to be returning in node.js

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

```
    function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("error", "Error connecting");
        result = "Failed";
        console.log(result)
    }
    else {
        sys.puts(stdout)
        result = "Success"
        console.log(result)
    }
    }

//The calling function is mentioned as below:
app.get('/api/platforms1', function(req, res){
    exec("ping localhost",puts);
});
```

//I am working under mean stack.I have created a method to ping ip address and display their result.But now I want to display the result as a return function.How can we do it??

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "display the result as a return function."  Could you explain?

Comment: Can you explain more? what exactly you want to do?

Comment: The function as you can see "puts" .I want to return the value "result".Whenever we call the function as "exec(ping localhost,puts)"

Comment: Perhaps what you're looking for is here [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:**

In windows, if you use:

`ping google.com`

You will get only 4 information ping, but on Ubuntu, if you use that command, the ping can't stop until you stop it with `Ctrl+C`.

To fix this we need to use *-c* flag. The -c option tells ping program to stop after sending (or receiving) specified number of ECHO_RESPONSE packets.

**Second:**

you need to use `res.send` to send back the ping response but due to your `callback` function i.e **puts** you don't have the access for `res` and `req`.

Use this wrapper func to pass another arguments you want to access with your callback

```
function execute(command, callback, res) {
    exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        // Notice extra params I have passed here^,  ^
        callback(error, stdout, stderr, res);
    });
}
```

and you can use this as

```
    execute("ping -c 2 google.com", puts, /*pass extra params*/ res);
```

and catch extra params here after your `callback` function

```
                                    || 
                         ---------- \/

function execute(command, callback, res) {
  ...
}
```

**Complete code:**

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

function puts(error, stdout, stderr, res) {
        // Notice extra params here  ^
    if (error) {
        console.log("error", "Error connecting");
        result = "Failed";
        console.log(result)
    } else {
        sys.puts(stdout)
        result = "Success"
        console.log(result)
        //send response to client
        res.send(result)
    }
}

//The calling function is mentioned as below:
app.get('/api/platforms1', function(req, res) {
    execute("ping -c 1 google.com", puts, /*pass extra params*/ res);
});

function execute(command, callback, res) {
    exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        // Notice extra params I have passed here^,  ^
        callback(error, stdout, stderr, res);
    });
}
```

Ref:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/200989/ping-for-4-times

[Get the output of a shell command in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941083/get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

First of all `sys` is [deprecated](https://github.com/Ziv-Barber/officegen/issues/86) you can use `util` instead of it.

And if you want to get your result wherever, that thing you can do with `callback`, since `Node.js` nature is asynchronous.