# using of binary (golang) from nodejs application and use the output

Tags: javascript, node.js, go, child-process

I’ve a binary which is executable  (a golang cli) which I need to call from nodejs application and get the response.
for example when running the following

`fzr get apps` it will provide **list of apps** in json format

I’ve two main question

1. Where should I put this binary ? let say I need to add it to my repository/lib  ( I **don't want** to assume that this binary is available in the environment like my pc or docker image, i want it be bundle inside my node module )
2. How should I call it ? I read about child process https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process

is it the recommended way? or there is other lib which could help…

Comment: Look at this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12941083/1218512

Comment: @colminator - thanks, this answer the second question, what about the first :)