# How to call a specific python function from nodejs?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

There is a python module 'python-shell', but it calls the whole python program what if I just want to call a specific function of python from nodejs, is there any way ?

Thank you !

Comment: Please read the following article on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please checkout this answer for your question I hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23452742/4439699

Comment: Ruchir Thank you, but child_process is used to run the whole python script not an individual function.

Comment: var process = spawn('python',["./hello.py",
                            req.query.firstname,
                            req.query.lastname] ); store that function to hello.py in order to test it so you may have a module to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a short python program calling your function, and run it using the `child_process` module as shown [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941083/execute-and-get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-in-node-js). You'll be able to get standard output back.

Comment: Yes thanks, but is there another efficient way to do it , because here I need to create different python file for different functionality.

Comment: You could pass the function name as an argument to the python program, but as far as I know, there is no way to call a specific python function from NodeJS.