# Directly return ${stdout} instead of logging on console

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have an app creator and, using the [Username NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/username), I can get the OS' username with this:

```
Browser.ExecJS("username.sync()")
```

Tested on Electron.

So, this is the format my app creator uses to read from JS:

```
Browser.ExecJS("")
```

In this example, it's calling `username.sync()`. And it works.

But when running this:

```
Browser.ExecJS("const{exec}=require(`child_process`);exec(`jq -r '.next_var' /tmp/eventsheet.json`,(error,stdout,stderr)=>{if(error){console.log(`error:${error.message}`);return}if(stderr){console.log(`stderr:${stderr}`);return}console.log(`${stdout}`);return});")
```

It gets "0". And then correctly logs the `stdout` on console.
But, it should get the same as it logs on console, instead of "0".

Its inspired by this code about how to run a native shell program directly from Electron/NodeJS: https://stackabuse.com/executing-shell-commands-with-node-js/

So, I think it should replace the `console.log` by some sort of return.
How do I re-factor it? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**: based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50335035/5623661) suggested answer (that doesn't works), this is the closest template to put it to work using `return` instead of `console.log` as output:

```js
const { promisify } = require('util');
const exec = promisify(require('child_process').exec)

module.exports.getGitUser = async function getGitUser () {
  const name = await exec('git config --global user.name')
  const email = await exec('git config --global user.email')
  return { name, email }
};
```

But still doesn't works.
What I need is this:

```js
const{exec}=require(`child_process`);exec(`jq -r '.next_var' /tmp/eventsheet.json`,(error,stdout,stderr)=>{if(error){console.log(`error:${error.message}`);return}if(stderr){console.log(`stderr:${stderr}`);return}console.log(`${stdout}`);return});
```

But using `return` instead of `console.log`.

Comment: It looks like you're using jq to read a value from a json file. You're using javascript so why don't you just open the file, use JSON.parse(), and then pull the value from the resulting object? It has to be a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help on making this simple and enabling it to work; but the purpose of this question isn't just about reading JSON (whether its jq or JSON.parse()), but about directly returning a value (in this case, the ${stdout}) when Electron/NodeJS are executing a shell program.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clarification. Does this answer your question? [Execute and get the output of a shell command in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941083/execute-and-get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-in-node-js)

Comment: A program can only ever return an integer as status code (and its range is OS-dependent). You would need to capture stdout.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer, this is the closest answer on your referred question/topic and the only that doesn't uses console.log: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50335035/5623661 but it haven't worked (also tested it on NodeJS by running "node test.js").