# Why is my virtual memory so large in a small nodejs app?

Tags: node.js, memory

UPDATED:

Apologies as I should have included more information in the initial post.

```
OS: macOS Sonoma 14.3.1
Memory: 32 GB
Node: Node 20.3.0
```

Here's the info from the macOS activity monitor
[image: memoryUsage image]

ORIGINAL:
I created a small testing js file here to view it's memory usage in nodejs.

```js
const start = () => {
  let num = 0;
  process.title = 'basicTest';
  const id = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(num++);
  }, 1000);
};
start();
```

When I run this process I see this data in the activity monitor. Here you can see the Virtual Memory Size is large (390 GB)

```
Real Memory Size    38.9 MB
Virtual Memory Size 390.30 GB
Shared Memory Size  12.0 MB
Private Memory Size 9.0 MB
```

I want to get a better understanding here since I've looked through a couple of SO and github posts about this and they seem to indicate that it shouldn't be an issue. All I want is to understand why is the virtual memory size so large (and is it possible to change this value?)

Here are some of the SO and github posts I've already read (but still don't understand why this is happening)

- [How to limit usage of virtual memory by node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762291/how-to-limit-usage-of-virtual-memory-by-node-js)
- https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/39499

Comment: Which activity monitor would this be? Because the only "Activity Monitor" I know is the MacOS one, and that doesn't list memory in the way you're showing in your post.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, if you double click on a process in Activity Monitor on macOS, it reports the memory exactly how it is described in the question, at least on macOS 12. Maybe the format changed in newer versions, I don't know.

Comment: Ignore the "Virtual Memory" size. It's often ridiculous because it includes the footprint of shared libraries mapped into your process.

Comment: @axiac: you learn something every day. I had never double clicked on an entry in activity monitor. But yeah those virtual memory numbers are completely meaningless, and appear to include the entire OS and then some. Have a look at the reported footprints for Finder or a random Terminal that you haven't done anything with other than "open it". See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42446/vm-size-in-activity-monitor-hundreds-of-gb