# Running Meteor methods that insert mongo documents in their own Fiber

Tags: meteor

I'm attempting to run `ntwitter` streaming API to track tweets about a certain hashtag, populating the Mongo collection `Tweets` with each tweet.

I've hooked it up server side like so:

```
t = new nTwitter({
    consumer_key: credentials.consumer_key,
    consumer_secret: credentials.consumer_secret,
    access_token_key: credentials.access_token_key,
    access_token_secret: credentials.access_token_secret
});

Meteor.methods({
  trackTweets: function () {
    this.unblock; // this doesn't seem to work
    console.log('... ... trackTweets');
    var _this = this;
    t.stream(
        'statuses/filter',
        { track: ['#love'] },
        function(stream) {
            stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
              // app/packages/mongo-livedata/collection.js:247
              //         throw e;
              //               ^
              // O yes I love her like money
              // Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber
                console.log(tweet.text);
                Tweets.insert(tweet.text); // this call blocks
            });
            stream.on('error', function(error, code) {
                console.log("My error: " + error + ": " + code);
            });
        }
    );
  }
});
```

The line: `Tweets.insert(tweet.text)` throws the `must run inside its own Fiber error` – and I've tried putting the `this.unblock` statement in several different places.

What should I do here?

Answer (score 1):

you dont call the function unblock, you need to replace your

```
this.unblock;
```

with this:

```
this.unblock();
```

if that doesn't work i would think it has something to do with the way ntwitter is getting the data, you could try to add this

```
if (Meteor.isClient) return false;
```

so that the method doesn't run on the client, but only on the server

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code you are running server-side needs to be contained within a Fiber.
Some similar examples can be found in these answers:

[Meteor code must always run within a Fiber” when calling Collection.insert on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192938/meteor-code-must-always-run-within-a-fiber-when-calling-collection-insert-on-s)

[Stream stdout to Meteor website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097007/stream-stdout-to-meteor-website)