# What other web-based tech can execute programs?

Tags: php, javascript, html, web-applications, asp-classic

In php there is `shell_exec()` for example, and you can run a program on the local server with it. But what other web-based technologies can do this and how?

Comment: This is a very broad question.  I would assume most server side languages would offer this kind of capability.  Is there a particular language you would like to know about?

Comment: Are you writing an encyclopedia?

Comment: Pretty much all of them.

Comment: HTML isn't a programming language, and JavaScript (running in a client's browser) can't run programs.

Comment: Hyper Text Markup LANGUAGE

Comment: @DavidHoude: I meant it's not a "programming" language :-)

Comment: I know just giving you a hard time ;)

Comment: Yes, it's a MARKUP Language ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP:

```
set wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
wshell.run "c:\file.bat" 
set wshell = nothing
```

Python:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["ls", "-l"])
```

Perl:

```
system("command arg1 arg2 arg3");
```

Ruby:

```
system("ls")
```

JSP/Servlet:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = 
   new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", "myfolder/myscript.sh > /myfolder/logs/myscript.log");
pb.start();
```

PHP:

```
shell_exec ( 'command' )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a cron job, CGI script with any supported language, and of course any web language (including Python, Ruby, Lisp, Java) which your web server can be configured to execute. That said, it's usually inadvisable to execute an application directly; it can lead to high server load and security exploits.

Answer (score 1):

For Javascript:

Client side, on Windows it could be done using ActiveX: [How to execute shell command in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880198/how-to-execute-shell-command-in-java-script). But it requires you to allow unsigned ActiveX controls, which introduces a major security issue.

And there is server-side Javascript, called [node.js](http://nodejs.org/). See the SO question [node.js execute system command synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443597/node-js-execute-system-command-synchronously) on how to use it to execute system commands.