# Execute git commands with node.js synchronously

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, exec, synchronization

I'm currently writing a node.js module. I'm using `var exec = require('child_process').exec;` from the node.js api. But I have to execute 2 git commands with exec successively. 
I always get the following error message:

> exec error: Error: Command failed: fatal: Unable to create
>   '~/Git/project/.git/index.lock': File exists.
>
> If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
>   git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
>   process is running and remove the file manually to continue.

I need to execute the seconed command after the first is finished - keyword: sync
So far I tried it with [execSync](https://github.com/mgutz/execSync) but it won't run on windows systems, which is a no go.

Currently I'm using the [asyncblock](https://github.com/scriby/asyncblock) module, but I gives me the error I mentioned above, too.

This happens when both values in the updateList are true, if one is false all works as expected.

```
var loadPackageJson = function(updateList){

        if(updateList.foo === true){
            update('foo/package.json');
        }

        if (updateList.bar === true){
            update('bar/package.json');
        }       
    };

        var update = function(path){
                var packageJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path,'utf8'));
                incrementVersion(packageJson);

                asyncblock(function(flow){
                    exec('git log -1 HEAD', flow.add('commit'));
                    var result = flow.wait('commit');
                    var commit=result.split('\n');
                    console.info(commit[0]);

                    setValueInPackageJson('commit', commit[0], packageJson);
                    writeUpdatedPackageJson(path, packageJson);

                    flow.wait();

                    exec('git add ' + path, flow.add('add'));
                    flow.wait('add'); //error is thrown here
                    console.info('added ' + path + ' successful to commit');
                });
    };
```

How can I execute both git commands synchronously?

/edit I know the following [Thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443597/node-js-execute-system-command-synchronously), but I helps me not to fix this problem. I found the hint with asyncblock on this thread.

/edit2 
The output on the console looks like the following:

```
Version: 0.6.14
Version: 0.0.901
commit a3ed4fd8545b736aa9feea1bea52c5e0aa6a07ac
foo/package.json successfully updated
commit a3ed4fd8545b736aa9feea1bea52c5e0aa6a07ac
bar/package.json successfully updated
```

In my eyes this looks like node parallelized the processing of the `loadPackageJson` function.

BR & Thanks,
mybecks

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood the question, but if exec is supposed to call the callback when the process is terminated, shouldn't something like `exec('got log -1 HEAD', function (err, stdout, stderr) { exec('git add ' + path); });`work?

Comment: hello, I tried it before and it still won't work.