# How to wait for a child process to finish in Node.js

Tags: node.js, child-process

I'm running a Python script through a child process in Node.js, like this:

```
require('child_process').exec('python celulas.py', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
});
```

but Node doesn't wait for it to finish. How can I wait for the process to finish?

Is it possible to do this by running the child process in a module I call from the main script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [node.js execute system command synchronously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443597/node-js-execute-system-command-synchronously)

Comment: Most of these answers don't work and the Nodejs documentation is terrible or non-existent :-/ How does a modern programming language have such difficulty with something so basic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use exec-sync

That allow your script to wait that you exec is done

really easy to use:

```
var execSync = require('exec-sync');

var user = execSync('python celulas.py');
```

Take a look at:
https://www.npmjs.org/package/exec-sync

Comment: Although this answer is correct, I highly recommend not using a synchronous method in node.js. This will completely block the application until the command is completed. See https://www.npmjs.org/package/execSync. It says to not use this for production.

Comment: Trying to figure out how to install this, but I get a wild list of errors when I try to run the npm install on this particular library.

Comment: @BryanJohnson perhaps a suggestion on what to use would be helpful.

Comment: @A.Wentzel I recommend a non-synchronous call described in alex's answer. execSync can work for simple scripts, but it seems I always end up regretting using synchronous methods.

Comment: exec-sync is broken now(2019). Just you the "vanilla" method. I posted it as an answer on this thread.

Comment: it more than 10 Years old, and repository is no longer maintained - it will not work (today).  The same feature is now built-in with node v0.12:  > https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options

Answer (score 111):

Use `exit` event for the child process.

```
var child = require('child_process').exec('python celulas.py')
child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
child.on('exit', function() {
  process.exit()
})
```

PS: It's not really a duplicate, since you don't want to use sync code unless you really really need it.

Comment: This is a better answer. You should avoid blocking (synchronous) code in Node wherever possible - it halts your entire program whilst waiting for the child process to finish.

Comment: There's also an `'end'` event, maybe different events are emitted for different calls (`exec()`, `spawn()`...)

Comment: The exit event isn't guaranteed to be fired. For instance, if the process failed to spawn, the error event is called. However, if the process did spawn and another error is caused, both handlers will be called.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Current correct answer blocks child process logs which are important.

Comment: This is the the answer to some other, opposite, question.

Comment: Won't the parent process exit before the child finishes?

Answer (score 38):

NodeJS supports doing this synchronously.
Use this:

```js
const execSync = require("child_process").execSync;
    
const result = execSync("python celulas.py");
    
// convert and show the output.
console.log(result.toString("utf8"));
```

Remember to convert the buffer into a string. Otherwise you'll just be left with hex code.

Answer (score 22):

A simple way to wait the end of a process in nodejs is :

```js
const child = require('child_process').exec('python celulas.py')

await new Promise( (resolve) => {
    child.on('close', resolve)
})
```

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, the best way to handle this is by implementing an event emitter. When the first spawn finishes, emit an event that indicates that it is complete.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const events = require('events');
const myEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();


firstSpawn = spawn('echo', ['hello']);
firstSpawn.on('exit', (exitCode) => {
    if (parseInt(exitCode) !== 0) {
        //Handle non-zero exit
    }
    myEmitter.emit('firstSpawn-finished');
}

myEmitter.on('firstSpawn-finished', () => {
    secondSpawn = spawn('echo', ['BYE!'])
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the listeners exec installs to add to the buffered stdout and stderr, even if you pass no callback it still buffers the output. Node will still exit the child process in the buffer is exceeded in this case.

```
var child = require('child_process').exec('python celulas.py');
child.stdout.removeAllListeners("data");
child.stderr.removeAllListeners("data");
child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `Util.promisify`, e.g.:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const Util = require('util');
const asyncExec = Util.promisify(exec);

asyncExec('python celulas.py')
.then((stdout, stderr) => {
    stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
    })
.catch(error => {
    console.log('error : ', error);
 });
```

Comment: where does child come from?

Answer (score 0):

I tried some of alternatives heres but does not worked for me... To resolve it in my case, I created an promise to await child.on('exit');

```
const promiseExec = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const myCmd = `sleep 15`;
      var child = exec(ffmpegCmd);
      child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
      child.on('exit', function() {
        resolve(child.stdout);
      })              
});

let stdout = await promiseExec;
// run the rest of my next this line
```

To understand: