# How to upgrade a specific package inside a Node file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-scripts

I have a `Node` project with the following structure:

```
.
├── index.js
├── package.json
├── updater.js
└── yarn.lock
```

I'm using `Yarn` with this project.

Inside file: `package.json` there is a reference to package: `@emotion/core@^10.0.22` as you can see below:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "@emotion/core": "^10.0.22",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

**What I need is:**

From inside file: `updater.js` file, upgrade package: `@emotion/core` to version: `^10.0.27` (just in case, remember I'm using `Yarn`), so I can do:

```
$ node updater.js
```

From the command line I can achieve this very easily with:

```
$ yarn upgrade @emotion/core@^10.0.27
```

But I need to do this from inside the file: `updater.js` (this is a requirement). This is a simplification of a biggest problem (so I need to meet the requirements of this dummy use case even if it doesn't make sense).

This code will go inside a custom package that will take care of installing some other packages.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will most likely have to run a script inside of `updater.js` that uses something like the `child_process` native module, see here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/35586247/5862900

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest will be using `child_process` to execute any script:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

 const childProcess = exec('yarn upgrade @emotion/core@^10.0.27', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
     console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
     console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
     if (error !== null) {
          console.log('exec error: ' + error);
     }
 });
```

You can check out more at [`node.js document page`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

You can pipe the stdio for close-to-realtime outputs by doing:

```
childProcess.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
```

But beware using `*Sync` (like `execSync`) libraries, you should `NOT` block code whenever possible. Better using `callback` or make it `Promise`

Also there are wonderful packages like [`shelljs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs) to encapsulate this.

Comment: this approach works but there is a problem with it, the output is not in real time. I mean, it seems that yarn is doing all his job on the background without giving the user any feedback and at the end when everything is done, al the output is shown to the user at once. Any idea on how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: @Viewsonic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22337446/how-to-wait-for-a-child-process-to-finish-in-node-js or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443597/node-js-execute-system-command-synchronously

Comment: As @goto1 said you can easily pipe the output.