# Why Child Process Skipped to run my Python Script?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-3.x, mocha.js

I have this js code:

```
const python = spawn('python', [path.join(settings.PROJECT_DIR, '/tests_explorer/scripts/product/product.py').replace(/\\/g, "/"), 'node.js', 'python']);

python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('Pipe data from python script ...');
  dataToSend = data.toString();
  console.log(dataToSend)
 });
```

It should execute my python Script product.py:

```
import sys
import general.general //my own utils
print('#Hello from python#')
print('First param:'+sys.argv[1]+'#')
print('Second param:'+sys.argv[2]+'#')
name = general.id_generator(9)
print(name)
```

But the node js seems skipped to run my python,
if I don't import general.general which is my own utils to generate random name, the python well executed and I can see the print data
Is anyone know how to solve this?
Thankyou

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wait for a child process to finish in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22337446/how-to-wait-for-a-child-process-to-finish-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

Check if it's present on the path (`process.env.PATH`), if `python` even exists on your system (it may be `python3` or `python2`) and if the path to the file is correct and perhaps not OS dependent:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const py = spawn('python3', ['-c', 'print("hello")']);
py.stdout.on('data', (data) => {console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);});
```

It works in CLI / REPL because it keeps the process open. However, in a file, it doesn't, therefore the event-based programming doesn't receive the event before the event loop manages to shutdown (kind of like `while (true) {}` in the background with consistent interrupts so your code can execute **in-between**).

For that you can utilize [`spawnSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options) which will block the program until the process is spawned, data interchanged and process closed.

```js
const { spawnSync } = require('child_process');
const py = spawnSync('python3', ['main.py']);
console.log(py.output.toString());
```

Or like in the linked question, `setTimeout()` or other system hacks to basically wait for the event loop to process your event (in this case `on("data", ...)` due to the [async nature of the `child_process` module](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_asynchronous_process_creation).