# How can I get the latest commit hash from Gruntfile.js?

Tags: node.js, windows, git, gruntjs

What I'm trying now is to use shelljs, but for some reason shell.exec('git rev-parse HEAD') just hangs.

This is my code:

```
function getLatestCommit() {
    return shell.exec("git rev-parse HEAD", {
        silent: true,
    }).output.trim().substr(0, 7);
}
```

Does anyone know any other way to achieve this?

I'm working on windows...

Answer (score 0):

`shell.exec` uses a callback. You're passing a parameter to it, but not utilizing the callback:

```
var shell = require('child_process');

function getLatestCommit() {
    shell.exec("git rev-parse HEAD", { silent: true }, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(error, stdout);
    });
}
getLatestCommit();
```

Comment: we are talking about diferent shell modules, I was using the shelljs module while you assume child_process. However I will consider your suggestion.
I ended up doing it the hard way: reading .git/HEAD file contents, no child process.

Comment: Ah, wasn't sure - you didn't indicate that in your post. Still, I believe they both behave the same way.

Comment: I did, is the 9th word of my question ;)
Anyway your approach is better than mine as you are not using an external module. The reason I didn't use the callback was that I wanted a synchronous function.

Comment: OH haha! Missed that completely. And I see what you're saying about wanting a synchronous function - in that case, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443597/node-js-execute-system-command-synchronously