# Return the result of execFile in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to get the result back from a execFile call:

```js
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(execute());
    return res.end();
  });
}).listen(8080);


var execute = function(){
  console.log("start execution");
    let result = execFile('./demo-files/demo.sh', ['1st', '2nd', '3rd'], function(err, data){
    if(err){
      console.log("ERROR:\n" + err);
    }
    return data.toString();
  });
  return result;
}
```

But I'm not sure which way is the right syntax.

Surprisingly, I can't seem to find the *exact post* on SO with my question? If duplicate, I will happily consider the other source.

Comment: The general solution to returning asynchronously retrieved data is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/816620).  In a nutshell, your  choices are to use a callback, a promise or an event.  You can't return the value directly unless you switch to `execFileSync()` which would not be advised for a server.

Comment: Try to execute sychronous command.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443597/node-js-execute-system-command-synchronously